# Fuse many csv files with same names from different directories

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 4 different folders which all contains  different csv files. The name of the csv files are same in all folders but the data within is from different time periods. I would now like to fuse all the files with same name into one.

Example of how it looks now:

```
                     ###################
                     #   MAIN_FOLDER   #
#############################################################
#  Folder1    #    Folder2    #    Folder3    #    Folder4  #
#-----------------------------------------------------------#
# A_foo.csv   #   A_foo.csv   #   A_foo.csv   #   A_foo.csv #
# A_bar.csv   #   A_bar.csv   #   A_bar.csv   #   A_bar.csv #
# B_foo.csv   #   B_foo.csv   #   B_foo.csv   #   B_foo.csv #
# B_bar.csv   #   B_bar.csv   #   B_bar.csv   #   B_bar.csv #
#             #               #               #             # 
#############################################################
```

So main category `A` has different subcategories `_foo` and `_bar`. As do `B`. ( in reality there is more than A-Z and around 30 subcategories)
I want to loop over all possible main categories and their respective subcategories. Then merge the ones with same name without overwriting any data. The csv files should look alike with same columns and index. However some of them have the index, which is unix datetime, in normal datetime. But I can fix that once the files are merged.

Example of end result:

```
for folder in MAIN_FOLDER:
    for category in MAIN_CATEGORIES:
        for subcategory in SUBCATEGORIES:
             file=folder+'/'+category+'_'+subcategory+'.csv'         
                 if name_of_file is same:
                    merge_file_into_one_without_overwriting_any_data()


#################
#  MAIN_FOLDER  #
#---------------#   
#   A_foo.csv   #
#   A_bar.csv   #
#   B_foo.csv   #
#   B_bar.csv   #
#               # 
#################
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this which worked as I wanted it to.

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

CONCAT_DIR = "new_path"

files = pd.DataFrame([file for file in glob.glob("/MAIN_FOLDER/*/*")], columns=["fullpath"])

files_split = files['fullpath'].str.rsplit("/", 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'path', 1:'filename'})

files = files.join(files_split)

for f in files['filename'].unique():
    paths = files[files['filename'] == f]['fullpath'] 
    dfs = [pd.read_csv(path, header=None,error_bad_lines=False) for path in paths]
    concat_df = pd.concat(dfs) 
    concat_df.to_csv(CONCAT_DIR + f) 
    print(concat_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
import os
from glob import glob
import csv

result = [y for x in os.walk("MAIN_FOLDER") for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.csv'))]

rows = []
for f in result:
    reader = csv.reader(open(f, "rb"))
    for row in reader:
        rows.append(row)

writer = csv.writer(open("OUTPUT.csv", "wb"))
writer.writerows("\n".join(rows))
```

Comment: Will this fuse only the ones with same names and create new separate files, or will this fuse all of them? I ask because I don't see how it saves them separately.

Answer (score 1):

In a bash script, this can also be solved for a given category and subcategory with:

```
find . -name "A_foo.csv" | xargs cat | dd of=A_foo.csv
```

It should be run for all categories and subcategories from the MAIN_FOLDER.
For example (contents of the script):

```
#!/bin/bash

cats='A B C'
subcats='foo bar'

for c in $cats
do
   for s in $subcats
   do
      files=${c}'_'${s}'.csv'
      find . -name "*$files*" | xargs cat | dd of=$files
   done
done
```

Comment: Is it this part `dd of=$files` that fuses the files? And when using this script, where are they automatically saved? in the `MAIN_FOLDER`?

Comment: Exactly, the dd command creates the file with the same name. If the script is run in the MAIN_FOLDER then files with the same names as the ones in the directory tree are created there.

Comment: i ran this in main_folder, it created a new file with the first cat and subcat it then proceeded to fill this file with numerical data until my extra discspace of 250gb was filled then cancelled because of diskspace error. The csv data I have is under 5gb.

Answer (score 1):

The filenames in all folders are identical, so you only need to iterate over one of the subfolders.  Once you have the filename, you can just plug in the other folder names.

```
folder1 = "Folder1"
other_folders = ["Folder2", "Folder3", "Folder4"]

for filename in os.listdir(folder1):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        for other_folder in other_folders:
            otherfilename = os.path.join(other_folder, filename)
            # now process otherfilename
```

Comment: How would I go about processing `otherfilename` so that it's safely saved?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "merge".

Comment: With merge I mean that I want to make a file which contain all the data from all the files with the same name, and to do this for all the names. With safely i mean so that no data is overwritten and that it keeps its structure.

Comment: Do you want to make a _new_ file that has the info for all of the A_foo.csv files?  Or do you want to pick one of the existing A_foo.csv files and append the other file's info?

Comment: I wont be needing the files after they are fused, only the one which contains all the data, so whichever is easiest is best.

Comment: Open `otherfilename` for reading, open `filename` for writing, write all the lines into filename.

Comment: My skills in handling csv files in python are not sufficient to figure out how to combine those instructions with your above answer. How do I write all the lines, instead of just some? Do you mean I should just add pd.read_csv(otherfilename)? How do I use df.to_csv() so that only files with same filenames are fused? I'm also unsure about what your code does, does it only provide the path to the files? Thanks